# Django ORM: get queryset of one field type

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model `ProblemVote` which contains `user` (`ForeignKey`), `problem` (`ForeignKey`) and `status` field. I need all the problems (which has been voted) with status 'AC' and 'R'.

I am able to fetch all the required problems in a Python list. However, i want to know if there is a better way using queryset methods.

Part of my code:

```
    all_votes = ProblemVote.objects.filter(
        user=user).select_related("problem").filter(problem__stage='PV')

    all_votes_problems = [vote.problem for vote in all_votes]
    accepted_problems = [vote.problem for vote in all_votes if vote.status == 'AC']
    rejected_problems = [vote.problem for vote in all_votes if vote.status == 'R']
```

Getting the problem as a queryset will help me in finding the count as `queryset.count()` and in finding queryset differences like `queryset.difference(another_queryset)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want is actually a `Problem` queryset and not a `ProblemVote` queryset?

If so you should use the `Problem` model and the double underscore notation in filter to get what you want.
Something like:

```
all_problems = Problem.objects.filter(stage='PV', vote__user=user)
accepted_problems = Problem.objects.filter(stage='PV', vote__user=user, vote__status='AC')
rejected_problems = Problem.objects.filter(stage='PV', vote__user=user, vote__status='R')
```

Making sure to change the `vote` in the filter calls to whatever the foreign key accessor actually is in your model (the `related_name` attribute on the foreign key field).

**EDIT**: Changed the filter calls due to the way Django processes queries on foreign key fields as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)